# Commutation relation for Lie algebras using the root string

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$ be roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ (relative to some choice of $\mathfrak{h}$) for which $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$, and let $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ denote the $\alpha$ weight space (similarly for $\beta$).
The $\alpha$-root string through $\beta$ is the set $$R(\alpha, \beta) = \{ \beta + k \alpha : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \Phi.$$
Define $V_{\alpha, \beta} = \sum_{\gamma \in R(\alpha, \beta)} \mathfrak{g}_\gamma$.
I know that there exists an isomorphic copy of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \subset \mathfrak{g}$ generated by $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$ (specifically a choice of $e_\alpha$ and $f_\alpha$) - denote this algebra by $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$.
I also know that if $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$ then the space $V_{\alpha,\beta}$ is an invariant irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$ (by way of restricting the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$).

I want to show that

> if $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$ then $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha, \mathfrak{g}_\beta] = \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta}.$

The proof in my textbook is summarised below, I have boldfaced the conclusion that I have tried to fill in the gaps for.

> First, we can check directly using the Lie bracket that $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha, \mathfrak{g}_\beta] \subset \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta}$.
> Since $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$, then $V_{\alpha,\beta}$ is irreducible under $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$, and by definition $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta} \subset V_{\alpha, \beta}$.
> **Then $e_\alpha$ maps $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ onto $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta}$.**

I first assume (for a contradiction) that there exists $X \in \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta}$ which does not come from the action of $e_\alpha$ on $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$.
Since each weight space has dimension 1, I know that $X$ spans $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta}$, which means that $e_\alpha$ sends $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ to 0.
This in turn implies that $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha, \mathfrak{g}_\beta] = 0$, since $e_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$.
Finally, I say that this shows that the action of $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$ on $V_{\alpha, \beta}$ is zero, contradicting the irreducibility of the representation.

It is this final statement that I am having the most trouble accepting, even though it seems correct to me.
Any input on if this is correct or not, and/or if there is an easier way to see the result, would be an ideal answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument works, but this is easier: $V_{\alpha,\beta}$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{s}(\alpha)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$. It follows that $e_\alpha$ only kills the highest weight vector, whose weight cannot be $\beta$, since $\alpha+\beta$ also occurs in the string. Because weight spaces are $1$-dimensional, the image of $\mathfrak{g}_\beta$ under $e_\alpha$ is precisely $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha+\beta}$.